# Bridges - How to prevent a big adversary to learn all bridges

Tags: bridge, censorship

Bridges exist in the Tor network to circumvent censorship by not publishing them all at the same time or as a full list. So far so good...

But how can a powerful adversary, like for example China, be prevented from learning all bridges? I read a lot about "not all bridges being published", etc. But I have a hard time to believe that this strategy really works against big players in the censorship business.

Or do I miss something?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It works, and exactly like this! To learn published bridges you need :

1. A working Perl + some modules(email-related)
2. A working list of emails **OR** a script to create ones
3. A...Tor client(!!!) for making an online requests for bridges via email as described [here](https://www.torproject.org/docs/bridges.html.en#FindingMore).

I've made such a script and had over 50 bridges in Russia, listed by IP addresses... A beer-box task, nothing complicated.

The more people will just run Tor, the less effective per-IP blocklists will be.